# Erro ao rodar projeto: Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument

Tags: android, arm

Não estou conseguindo fazer rodar minha aplicação, primeiramente saia um erro de memória corrigi para não ultrapassar a máxima em MB. Agora, sai este erro que não entendi direito, dizendo que o *arm é inválido*.

Como tirar este problema?

```
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduza o tamanho da memória RAM do emulador.

No Eclipse vá em: `Window` -> `Android Virtual Device Manager`, selecione o seu dispositivo e clique no botão `Edit` no lado direito da janela, em seguida em `Memory Options` procure pelo parâmetro **RAM** e configure para 512 por exemplo. Clique em `OK` para salvar. Agora tente rodar novamente a aplicação.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26631803/1608936)

Comment: Estou usando o Android Studio, eu mudo o valor da memória RAM e quando eu mando rodar, sai o mesmo erro e verifico ele volta na mesma memória que estava antes.

Comment: Ainda com alguns alertas... Mas consegui trocando e modelo do aparelho no emulador. Obrigado.